# Is it possible to have opencv2 and opencv3 on the same PC ? I am using ros noetic ubuntu 20.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ros, opencv3.0, ubuntu-20.04

I want to work sometimes with some files developed by opencv3 libraries and sometimes with opencv2, and since the files are so long I do not have the time to migrate from opencv2 into opencv3, it needs some experience also specially that the codes is not

I have not tried this because it may cause a conflict in my system files, that why I am asking if someone tried to use both versions on the same PC.

Comment: I recommend using virtual environments https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-virtual-environments-in-python/

Comment: use opencv v4. please stop using opencv v2. "cv2" (python) refers to the C++ API, as opposed to the C API, which no longer exists. the C++ API was introduced in OpenCV v2.